# plotly - remove or ignore "Non-leaves rows" for sunburst diagram

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plotly, plotly-python, sunburst-diagram

I have a DataFrame with some "Non-leaves rows" in it. Is there any way to get plotly to *ignore* them, or a way to automatically remove them?

Here's a sample DataFrame:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Alice | Bob |  |  |
| 1 | Alice | Bob | Carol | David |
| 2 | Alice | Bob | Chuck | Delia |
| 3 | Alice | Bob | Chuck | Ella |
| 4 | Alice | Bob | Frank |  |

In this case, I get the error `Non-leaves rows are not permitted in the dataframe` because the 0th row is not a distinct leaf.

I've tried using `df = df.replace(np.NaN, pd.NA).where(df.notnull(), None)` to add the `None` to the empty values, but the error persists.

Is there any way to have the non-leaves ignored? If not, is there a simple way to prune them? My real dataset is several thousand rows.

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm struggling w/ the same issue ;;-;;

Comment: I ended up hand-editing part of Plotly to allow it. My patch is at https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3589

Answer (score 0):

One way is to reshape your dataframe with unique relations parent-child. Here is one way:

```
import plotly.express as px

cols = df.columns
data = (
    pd.concat(
        [df[[i,j]].rename(columns={i:'parents',j:'childs'})
         for i,j in zip(cols[:-1], cols[1:])])
      .drop_duplicates()
)

fig = px.sunburst(data, names='childs', parents='parents')
fig.show()
```